# How to output numbers between first and last perfect square from file?

Tags: c++, file, square

I have a file("bac.txt) with the numbers `11 245 36 67 8 576 11 16 41 144 67 89 1011` in it (it's an unknown amount of numbers).
The first perfect square is 36 and the last one is 144 and I have to output the numbers between these 2, so the output has to be `36 67 8 576 11 16 41 144`. I managed to get the last one, but can't figure out how to memorize the first one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("bac.txt");
    int n, rp, x;
    int first = INT_MAX, last = INT_MAX;
    int cnt = 0, cnt2 = 0;

    while(f >> n){
        rp = sqrt(n);
        if(rp * rp == n)
            last = n;
        if((rp * rp == n) && n < first)
            first = n;
    }
    cout << first << " " << last;
    return 0;
}
```

This one only outputs the smallest one and the last one (I haven't tried to output the ones in-between).

Comment: The very first perfect square you see in your loop would have to be the first perfect square in the file. You could have `int first = -1`, and your condition could then just be `if(first == -1 && (rp * rp == n)){first = n;}`. When `first == -1`, that represents that you haven't seen a square yet.

Comment: Your condition of `((rp * rp == n) && n < first)` would, as you said, output the smallest square number in the file and not necessarily the first one. This is because `n < first` checks if the square *itself* is less than `first`. Perhaps you meant to check if the index of the square in the file is less than `first`?

Comment: @Telescope and every time I find a new perfect square I do +1 to the `first` so it keeps the first one right?

Comment: @Telescope and for the 2nd comment yes I knew what it did, I was just experimenting, however how could I get the index if I don't have a known number of elements in the file?

Comment: If you want to keep the first perfect square, you should not be changing `first` after you've found any perfect square. If you found, say, 49 at the beginning of the file, then `first` is fixed; you already know that no other square *can* be the first square in the file. In other words, `first` should only change once: when you find the first perfect square. As for getting the index, you can keep a variable `int index = 0` and increment it every time you input a new integer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah i couldn't put the "perfect square" as a standalone tag

Comment: @Telescope how do i get the positions of the first and the last perfect squares?